# Saved Preferences on a NSTextField are not set upon initialising

Tags: macos, cocoa, singleton, sharedpreferences

I don't understand why my saved preferences are not shown in my settings window upon initialization.

I'm saving settings in a .plist file and load them up on `applicationDidFinishLaunching` like this:

```
// AppDelegate.m

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    if (!self.settingsWindow) {
        self.settingsWindow = [[SettingsWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"SettingsWindow"];
    }

    [[Settings sharedSettings] load_settings]; // My Singleton Class where I store Settings

    [self loadup_settings]; // Here I load up the settings, saved somwhere in a property list file.

}

- (void) loadup_settings
{

    field_username.stringValue = [[Settings sharedSettings] username];
    field_password.stringValue = [[Settings sharedSettings] password];
    server_id.title = [[Settings sharedSettings] server_id];
    server_language.title = [[Settings sharedSettings] server_language];

    // here I set the stringValue of the fieldUserAgent. But now when I want to
    // show the window, the stringValue is empty. Why is that?
    self.settingsWindow.fieldUserAgent.stringValue = [[Settings sharedSettings] user_agent];

}

- (IBAction) openSettingsWindow:(id)sender
{
    // show settings window on button click. but fieldUserAgent is empty :(
    [self.settingsWindow showWindow:self];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:-

In your SettingsWindowController.m class inside - (void)windowDidLoad method set the value:-

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    self.userAgent.stringValue=[[Settings sharedSettings] user_agent];
    [super windowDidLoad];

// Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
}
```

Comment: ok this works, but the stringValue is `null` until I click on `openSettingsWindow`, where then the stringValue gets set. Isn't there a way to set it right upon initialization?

Comment: But you only want to display the data after window has been displayed so this will be the better way